# Replace numpy array value on condition with random number

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, vectorization

I need to replace some values in a numpy array based on a condition with a random number.

I have a function that adds a random value 50% of the time:

```
def add_noise(noise_factor=0.5):

    chance = random.randint(1,100)
    threshold_prob = noise_factor * 100.

    if chance <= threshold_prob:
        noise = float(np.random.randint(1,100))
    else:
        noise = 0.

    return(noise)
```

But when I call the numpy function, it replaces all matching values with the random number generated:

```
np.place(X, X==0., add_noise(0.5))
```

The problem with this, is that add_noise() only runs once, and it replaces all the 0. values with the noise value.

What I am trying to do is "iterate" through every element in the numpy array, check the condition (is it ==0.) and I want to generate the noise value through add_noise() every time.

I could do this with a for loop going through every row and column, but does anyone know of a more efficient manner of doing it?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: Yes, the vectorized approach was good. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach -

```
noise_factor = 0.5 # Input param

# Get mask of zero places and the count of it. Also compute threshold
mask = X==0
c = np.count_nonzero(mask)
threshold_prob = noise_factor * 100.

# Generate noise numbers for count number of times. 
# This is where vectorization comes into the play.
nums = np.random.randint(1,100, c)

# Finally piece of the vectorization comes through replacing that IF-ELSE
# with np,where that does the same op of choosing but in a vectorized way
vals = np.where(nums <= threshold_prob, np.random.randint(1,100, c) , 0)

# Assign back into X
X[mask] = vals
```

Additional benefit is that we are re-using the `mask` of `0s` for the `add_noise` operation and also for assigning back into `X`. This replaces the use of `np.place` and is meant as an efficiency criteria.

**Further performance boost**

We could optimize further at the steps that compute `nums` and `vals` that use two steps of random number generation by doing that instead once and re-using at the second step, like so -

```
nums = np.random.randint(1,100, (2,c))
vals = np.where(nums[0] <= threshold_prob, nums[1] , 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could vectorize your function, which makes it easy to apply to every element and is also quite efficient I suppose.

```
import random
import numpy as np

def add_noise(x):
    if not x:
        if random.random() <= 0.5:
            noise = float(np.random.randint(1,100))
            return noise
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        return x

x = np.zeros(shape=(10, 10))

n = np.vectorize(add_noise)
x = n(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to change values of a numpy array to a random value based on two conditions.

1. value should be zero
2. some random chance factor

For these two conditions you can create two masks and combine them with `np.logical_and`. And you can use the `np.random` methods to get arrays of random numbers.

```
import numpy as np

def add_perhaps_noise_if_zero(x, threshold=0.5):
    mask_1 = x == 0.0
    mask_2 = np.random.random(x.shape) <= threshold
    mask_combined = np.logical_and(mask_1, mask_2)
    x[mask_combined] += np.random.random(x.shape)[mask_combined]
    return x


x = np.zeros((5,5))
for i in range(5):
    print(x)
    x = add_perhaps_noise_if_zero(x)
```