# Replacing an element of a 2D matrix with a random number in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, random

I have a 2D matrix `A=[[27  1 63 66 79],[55 20 40 26 68],[42 64 96 27 14]]`. I want to replace every element greater than 20 with a random number. Is there a way to replace it with a new random number every time a entry greater than 20 is detected. I don't want to use the for loop and iterate over each entry.
I am using this `A[A>20]= np.random.randint(0,9)`. However in this technique each entry greater than 20 is replaced with a fixed random number.

Comment: What is your "array"? A list of lists or a numpy array?

Comment: Would you mind adding the commas to your lists so they become actual lists

Comment: Maybe take a look at `numpy.vectorize`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace numpy array value on condition with random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517414/replace-numpy-array-value-on-condition-with-random-number)

Comment: 'A' is a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a numpy array. You need to generate a random array of the same shape.

```
A = np.where(A>20, np.random.randint(0,9, size=A.shape), A)
```

Example output:

```
array([[0, 8, 3, 0, 2],
       [1, 4, 7, 5, 1],
       [5, 4, 8, 7, 6]])
```

Comment: This worked fine!